# Getting unique numbers efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, math

The problem in question is to check an equation, example:

a * b / c + d = x

Where a - d are unique numbers from 1 - 4.

Now obviously you could run through all the possibilities, then skip when it has duplicates, but this would be O(n^n), when you should be able to solve this with O(n!) but I can't figure out how.

Is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: Make a list and remove each number when you pick it...

Comment: Yeah, getting each numbers once isn't the problem, it's trying out every unique combination.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your wording ("*a - d are unique numbers from 1 - 4*") it seems that you want is an algorithm for generating all possible permutations of a set of numbers - in your case the set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Given the size of the set, the algorithm is best implemented recursively: for every element in the set (from left to right) generate all the permutations of the remaining elements. Note that once you get to the last element, there's obviously only one possible order.

This approach basically reduces the problem of finding the permutations of N items to finding the permutations of N-1 items.

Here's how it would look like on the set `{1, 2, 3}` which we expect will have six permutations:

```
{1, 2, 3}
1 | {2, 3}
1 | 2 | {3}
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | {2}
1 | 3 | 2
2 | {1, 3}
2 | 1 | {3}
2 | 1 | 3
2 | 3 | {1}
2 | 3 | 1
3 | {1, 2}
3 | 1 | {2}
3 | 1 | 2
3 | 2 | {1}
3 | 2 | 1
```

So this algorithm gives us the following six permutations:

```
123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321
```

You can find a lot of information on the Wikipedia article on Permutations, including [permutation generation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations).

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see any algorythm different from a factorial formula to efficiently solve this. And you not mentioned if B and C should be avoided in the repetition too.

Anyway, I guess if won´t have to consider D with the same values of A, since, unavoidable, there are similar results between them.

I believe the *best* way to solve this witout a factorial formula is really using a LOOKUP TABLE (try a BYTE ARRAY to speed), where you need to find each repeated value to discard it.

Again: I´m not considering repetitions between B and C.

Comment: ABCD  
ABDC  
ACBD  
ACDB  
ADBC  
ADCB  etc.